# How do I specify only one font style when using @font-face with only one .ttc file which contains both styles

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

My website uses a font that Google Fonts does not have, so I used "@font-face". which looked like this.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Font';
src: local(example.ttc);
}
```

This method worked and my font that I uploaded was displayed. The only problem is that the font I'm using has 2 styles (inline and solid) and I don't know how to specify it (there is only one .ttc file for both styles). I tried `font-style: solid` and `font-family: 'Font Solid';` and many other ways but none of them worked. Does anybody know how to specify only one style? Thanks!

**PS-** I replaced "Font" and "example.ttc" with their actual names in my real code.

**PPS-** Sorry if my question is vague or too specific. Just tell me and I'll clear it up.

Comment: Did you mean outline instead of inline? Also, please confirm that you put those other properties you mention inside the `@font-face` rather than in the body style.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it says "inline", but the font I'm using is called "Phosphate". Maybe if you looked it up online you would get a better idea of what I mean. It's probably hard to help me if you don't know the specifics, sorry ;)

Comment: And yes, I did put the properties that you mentioned in the "@font-face".

Comment: Hm, inline. Interesting. Never heard it being called that. It's still outline though! Anyway, I don't have any ttc fonts on my computer, so I can't test, but isn't there any tool that can show the _exact_ font names as stored in a font file? (For instance, my search ended up with font names like "Phosphate RR Solid" and such. If that's the exact name, that's what you should use.)